# Design Guidelines: Duplicate item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, design-guidelines

What are the design guidelines for duplicating an item in a `RecyclerView`?

I already implemented the following gestures:

- **Swipe right:** remove item
- **Click:** open another Activity with item details
- **Long click:** reorder items

My idea for duplicating an item:

- **Swipe left:** I think the user would never know without me telling him. Also, does not seem to be intuitive to me
- **Double tap:** I heard it is against the guidelines
- **Long click:** out of question because it is reserved for triggering the reorder operation
- **a seperate (Button) View** within the item with an `onClick` event (seems legit, but messes up the design (because of the redundance) if any `RecylcerView` item has one. Leaving this button invisible by default and triggering it to appear would also not be efficient or intuitive in my eyes.)
- ???

What should I do?

Please don't mind the data in those examples. It is just test data.

Current design:

[image]

Design with additional buttons (just to show my point, no final design):

[image]

**In my opinion it is redundant to have the same button over and over again. It just does not look good.**

Look at it [live](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.randomlychosenbytes.caloriescount), if you want.

Comment: a separate button for duplicating doesnt sounds like a issue

Comment: technically not, but like i said... the redundance does not look so good

Comment: what do you mean by redundance, please explain clearly

Comment: well a separate button i mean in UI and not in RV

Comment: +1 to @ankitagrawal, I'd also go with a button, I guess icon would be better. It shouldn't be a big problem on the UI because of the small icon and also it doesn't seem there will be anything more intuitive than that because this is not really common action that you do with a recycler view, so I double people expect something more intuitive than just an icon.

Comment: well did you try my opinion

Comment: it is an interesting idea, but actually I would like to avoid a mode switch. I want something that can happen right away.

Comment: well you dont have to switch mods for that

Comment: if i have to press a button, to make other buttons appear which are usually not visible, it is an (input) mode switch for me. does not matter, I just don't think it is fast nor intuitive. :(

Answer (score 0):

My idea for duplicating an item:

Swipe left: I think the user would never know without me telling him. Also, does not seem to be intuitive to me:  - **yes bad idea**

Double tap: I heard it is against the guidelines - **well upto but yes user wont know this**

Long click: out of question because it is reserved for triggering the reorder operation - **okk**

a seperate (Button) View within the item with an onClick event (seems legit, but messes up the design (because of the redundance) if any RecylcerView item has one. Leaving this button invisible by default and triggering it to appear would also not be efficient or intuitive in my eyes.)
    ???

What should I do?
My Suggestion:-

**well a separate button in UI and not in RV and if you want to duplicate a particular item provide check box for selecting which item to duplicate**